# Setting downtimes in Nagios/Icinga via SCCM

Tags: nagios, windows-server-2012-r2, sccm, icinga

At our company we have quite a lot of Windows 2012/2008 servers which are updated automatically (and sometimes rebooted) via SCCM. All our servers are monitored via Icinga/Nagios. If the servers are rebooted during the update process we get "false" alarms.

Our linux servers are also updated automatically (and rebooted if a new kernel was installed). We scripted our own update procedure and call a webservice to schedule downtime for the affected host. The webservice does some security and sanity checks and uses Icingas external command file to schedule the downtime.

Now, I was wondering if there's any possibility to call the webservice via SCCM during the update process? Any suggestions?

Comment: does SCCM not have a way to call the same webservice?

Comment: According to my co-workers: unfortunately not.

Comment: SCCM 2012 SP1 has a Linux agent, which might help you, but I don't really have an answer, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built-in to CM12 for this however you could write a custom action to apply patching via a Task Sequence or use orchestrator to do that same thing.